# Extract Returned values from 'VirtualNetworkPeering object

Tags: azure-sdk-python

How Can I extract the atrribute values returned from list of peered virtual networks. 
I executed this command and I need to extract the Network ID

```
list_all = network_client.virtual_network_peerings.list(
    GROUP_NAME,
    VNET_NAME
)
```

for peer in list_all:

print(peer)

and I get this value for from the print above:

```
{'additional_properties': {'type': 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings'}, 
'id': '/subscriptions/c70b9b-efd6-497d-98d8-e1e1d497425/resourceGroups/azure-sample-group-virtual-machines/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/azure-sample-vnet/virtualNetworkPeerings/sample-vnetpeer', 
'allow_virtual_network_access': True, 
'allow_forwarded_traffic': True, 
'allow_gateway_transit': False, 
'use_remote_gateways': False, 
'remote_virtual_network': <azure.mgmt.network.v2018_08_01.models.sub_resource_py3.SubResource object at 0x048D6950>, 
'remote_address_space': <azure.mgmt.network.v2018_08_01.models.address_space_py3.AddressSpace object at 0x048D68D0>,
 'peering_state': 'Initiated', 
'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded',
 'name': 'sample-vnetpeer',
 'etag': 'W/"653f7f94-3c4e-4275-bfdf-0bbbd9beb6e4"'}
```

How can I get this value "remote_virtual_network"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that your question is actually more a Python question than an Azure question. Assuming in your application this field is set with values, then `remote_virtual_network` is a `SubResource` meaning it only has one attribute: `id`

```
for peer in list_all:
    remote_virtual_network_id = peer.remote_virtual_network.id
```

This guy is an actual virtual network, so if you want details about it you need to get it with `network_client.virtual_networks.get`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_08_01.operations.virtualnetworksoperations?view=azure-python#get

The tricky part is you get an ID, but VNet get asks for a RG name and VNet name, you can use the ARM ID parser for that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure/msrestazure.tools?view=azure-python#parse-resource-id

Comment: Thanks Laurent, That what I was looking for a python question how I would retrieve the value, adding the id did it

Answer (score 0):

'remote_virtual_network': , 
'remote_address_space':

I will try this out and get back:

This command is analogous to "get-azurermvirtualnetworkpeering -ResourceGroupName -VirtualNetworkName -Name" on Azure PowerShell.

remote_virtual_network you don't have one. You will only get this if you have Remote Gateway enabled and the Peer will learn the IP address of the Remote (On-premise site) that you are trying to connect.

To get this value, deploy a gateway in the Vnet and connect it to Say "Vnet-S2S-test" with a gateway deployed there as well.

Once, the Site-to-site between the Vnets are up. You can execute the command and you should see those fields populated with the local network gateway details.